# Can every multivariate distribution be expressed as a function of univariate distributions of the same random variables?

Tags: probability, distributions, copula, multivariate-distribution

Can every multivariate distribution $p(X)$ of a multivariate random variable $X = [X_1, X_2, \dots, X_d]^{T} \in \mathbb{R}^d$, be defined as some function of univariate distributions on $X_i$?

I cannot think of any reason this should be true, but I cannot find a counterexample.

Comment: What is a "combination"? // Depending on your answer, you might be interested in [Sklar's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Sklar's_theorem), which seems to answer your question in the affirmative.

Comment: @Dave have changed "combination" to "function" since that is more appropriate.

Comment: Did you intend to change the title as well?

Comment: @Glen_b have updated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**YES**

This is [Sklar's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Sklar%27s_theorem).

Let $H(x_1,\cdots,x_d) = \mathbb P\big(X_1 < x_1,\cdots,X_d<x_d\big)$ be a multivariate CDF, and let $F_i$ be the marginal CDFs. Then there is a function, $C$, called a copula, such that $H(x_1,\cdots,x_d) = C\big(F_{1}(x_1),\cdots,F_{d}(x_d)\big)$.

Depending on how gross the multivariate distribution is, it is possible to write this as a density, which I find more intuitive. In some regard, this is just the product of the margins times some function that governs (or describes) the dependence structure.

$$
h(x_1,\cdots,x_d) = \bigg(\prod f_i(x_i)\bigg)\times c\big(F_{1}(x_1),\cdots,F_{d}(x_d)\big)
$$

Comment: why don't you start your answer with saying clearly YES first, then explaining the theorem. otherwise, it's not clear to a novice that you say so

Comment: Is "gross" a technical term? (genuine question)

Comment: @AbhishekDivekar Distributions in introductory classes all have probability density or probability mass functions: normal, exponential, geometric, Poisson, etc. As one progresses further in probability, one encounters that these are exceptional, and there is a sense that makes mathematical sense where "almost all" distributions lack densities. *Those* are what I would gross, but, no, that is not a technical term. (You'll see this kind of slang in mathematics. For instance, in my undergrad real analysis class, my prof said, "This isn't true in general but is for decent functions.")

Comment: This is indeed the right answer. When the distributions are continuous we have unique existence of a copula, while only existence is satisfied for discrete distributions.

Comment: @Dave yeah I guess "well-behaved" is a common term used to describe certain functions, as if other functions were naughty children who need to be reprimanded :)